# Is it possible in PHP to $_GET via a parent page?

Tags: php

I have a page `view.php?id=1` initialising a DataTable via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                    "url": "core/server_processing/order.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                    }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Is it possible for a script running within `core/server_processing/order.php` to know the ID of the parent page?

I tried `$_GET['id']` but it doesn't work as it is expecting `core/server_processing/order.php?id=1` probably.

Comment: Why don't you just transfer the originating URL as post params? `"data": { "referer": location.href }` and `$_POST['referer']`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Those are separate HTTP requests; PHP doesn't even know *which* other possible previous request you may be wanting to refer to. And since PHP has nothing do to with how pages/frames/data are nested on the client side, there's no "parent" it could refer to either.

Simply explicitly pass the parameter through in your AJAX request.